# PropertyChangedEventHandler usage question

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an event, `PropertyChangedEventHandler` and I raise it like this:

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LogFile"));
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Nodes"));
```

I also attached to it:

```
 PropertyChanged += UpdateCamxWindowEvent;
```

How can I execute `UpdateCamxWindowEvent` only when the event is raised with `"LogFile"`?

What I should change in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to execute specific method only for certain parameters, unless you created another event. What you should do is to change `UpdateCamxWindowEvent`, so that it actually does something only when the parameter is `LogFile`.

If you can't do that or it logically doesn't make sense in your application, you can add an handler that just tests the argument and if it matches, calls the method:

```
PropertyChanged += (s, e) => { if (e.PropertyName == "LogFile") UpdateCamxWindowEvent(s,e); };
```

Note that you wouldn't be able to unsubscribe this anonymous method from the event. If you need to do that, use normal method with the same functionality.

Comment: @ Akram Shahda , instead of PropertyChanged += UpdateCamxWindowEvent;

Answer (score 0):

If you need to fire the event always, you can check the event handler's arguments values in the event handler method to determine what are code instractions you want to call.